# Reusing context with object.track() breaks when trying to get parentContentControl

Tags: office-js

Context: When a click is detected, i try to detect if any paragraphs somehow do not have a contentControl. Therefore, it requires reusing the context. I have been able to get context reuse working, but not for this particular bit of code.

Therefore, a minimal reproduction on running a piece of code twice:

```
        let randomObject: Word.Document = null;
        await Word.run(async (context) => {
            randomObject = context.document;
            randomObject.track();
        })
        await Word.run(randomObject, async (context) => {
            await test(context);
        });

        await Word.run(randomObject, async (context) => {
            await test(context);
        });
```

This is the code which simply retrieves the first contentControl on the first paragraph. It does the following:

- Retrieve body
- Retrieve paragraphs
- Retrieve first item
- Retrieve parentContentControlOrNullObject

```
async function test(context: Word.RequestContext) {
    try {
        const body = context.document.body;
        await context.sync();
        const paragraphs = body.paragraphs;
        paragraphs.load('items');
        context.load(paragraphs);
        await context.sync();
        console.log('1111', paragraphs.items.length);
        const para = paragraphs.items[0];
        await context.sync();
        console.log('2222');
        const cc = para.parentContentControlOrNullObject;
        await context.sync();
        console.log('3333');
        await context.sync();
        console.log('done');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error: test', e);
        if (e instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(e.debugInfo));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

[image]

It clearly succeeds on the first run, but not the second.

The detailed errors are as follows:

```
{
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   code: "ItemNotFound",
   errorLocation: "ParagraphCollection.getItem",
   fullStatements: [ ],
   message: "ItemNotFound",
   statement: "var paragraph=paragraphs.getItem(...) /* originally getItem(...) */;",
   surroundingStatements: [ ],
   Symbol()_7.e7nkt729xmo: undefined,
   Symbol()_k.e7nkt729xt6: undefined,
   Symbol()_m.e7nkt729xt6: undefined,
   Symbol(Symbol._hidden)_l.e7nkt729xt6: undefined,
   Symbol(Symbol.observable)_n.e7nkt729xt6: undefined,
   Symbol(util.promisify.custom)_j.e7nkt729xt6: undefined
}
```

@michael-zlatkovsky Does not appear to be related to [Using Paragraph outside the Word.run flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585155/using-paragraph-outside-the-word-run-flow)

```
            const body = context.document.body;
            await context.sync();
            const paragraphs = body.paragraphs;
            paragraphs.load('items');
            context.load(paragraphs);
            await context.sync();
            console.log('xxxxxxxxxxx');
            const t = paragraphs.items[0].getRange();
            await context.sync();
            console.log('yyyyyyyyyyy');
```

Never gets to `yyyyyyyyyyy`.

Comment: I would recommend filing a bug on https://github.com/officedev/office-js/issues. 
I also wonder if it could be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585155/ (with a similar workaround possible, perhaps...)

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft i tested it, doesn't appear to have an identical fix.